# jqueryUI tooltip not showing the clock in a tooltip with modified width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to show a tooltip of the content i display on screen but with a changed width so in a tooltip, it should be bigger enough to display a clock,

i am planning it in two ways:
way #1

Based on the above, I do not see the code is wrong, but it does not display a tooltip and a clock inside it.

Now second way is: I am trying to display a div instead of canvas and say time now and then hover it will open a clock in a tooltip.

But wanted to know what is happening , so why the clock is not appearing in a tooltip.

I am exported the libraries accordingly.

```js
$("#customClock").htAnalogClock({
  fillColor: "rgba(255, 100, 255, 0.2)",
  fontColor: "#000",
  pinColor: "#f80",
  majorTicksColor: "#000",
  minorTicksColor: "#111",
  hourHandColor: "#00f",
  minuteHandColor: "#0f0",
  drawSecondHand: true
});

// Show jQueryUI tooltip on hover
$("#customClock").tooltip({

  content: function() {

    // Change the width of the canvas to 240
    $(this).attr("width", "240");

    // Re-initialize the analog clock with the new width
    $(this).htAnalogClock("destroy").htAnalogClock({
      fillColor: "rgba(255, 100, 255, 0.2)",
      fontColor: "#000",
      pinColor: "#f80",
      majorTicksColor: "#000",
      minorTicksColor: "#111",
      hourHandColor: "#00f",
      minuteHandColor: "#0f0",
      drawSecondHand: true
    });

    // Return the canvas element
    return $(this);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/analog-clock-timezone/jquery.ht-analog-clock.js"></script>

<canvas id="customClock" width="70"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, so that we don't have to go hunt down the libraries you used ourselves.

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yjthuf86/

Comment: All information must be in your post, not down here, and there's no need to send us to other sites. Please see [ask].

Comment: well i have added whatever was applicable, seems no one wants to answer